# How can I evaluate the limit of this function using series?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

**Limit as x approaches 0 of $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-cosx}{1+x-e^x}$**. I substituted in the Taylor series of $cosx$ and $e^x$ into the function, but it's still in $\frac{0}{0}$ form, and I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: Did you cancel $x^2$ from the numerator and the denominator?

Comment: Can you please show your work? It's unclear to which power you expanded the function into a Taylor's series?

Answer (score 1):

You did not go deeper enough in your Taylor series you need to go up to the term in $x^2$ to solve this limit.

$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)$ and $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)$.

So $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-cosx}{1+x-e^x}=lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-1+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)}{1+x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)}=lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)}{-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)}=-1$